# inner join tabela on 1 = 1 pode ser considerado uma gambiarra?

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Tenho uma tabela de `provas` e uma tabela de `alunos` que não possuem nenhum relacionamento direto, tenho ainda uma tabela de `inscrição aluno` e uma tabela de `escolas`, como segue na modelagem abaixo:

[image: DER]

Necessito criar um select para trazer quantos alunos de cada escola estão inscritos em cada prova.

Recorri a uma *gambiarra* com grandes ressalvas pois o `SELECT` funcionou perfeitamente:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(ia.idaluno) FROM inscricaoaluno ia INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.idaluno = ia.idaluno
WHERE a.idpessoa_juridica = e.idpessoa_juridica AND ia.idprova = p.idprova) qtd, e.nome, e.idpessoa_juridica , p.descprova, p.idprova  
FROM escolas e
INNER JOIN prova p ON 1 = 1 
GROUP BY e.nome, e.idpessoa_juridica , p.descprova, p.idprova  
ORDER BY e.nome;
```

"Criei um relacionamento inexistente" da tabela escola com a tabela prova usando um `INNER JOIN ON 1 = 1`, com isso eu listei todas as provas para cada escola, se eu tiver os seguintes dados por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse relacionamento "inexistente" me trará o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso crio uma *subquery* nos dados que me traz a quantidade de cada aluno em cada prova de acordo com a escola que ele estuda.

Agora vem aquela dúvida, isso é uma gambiarra? O resultado é satisfatório, funciona, mas muitas pessoas não veem com bons olhos a utilização do artifício do `1 = 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, é uma gambiarra isso. O correto nesse caso seria aplicar um `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT (SELECT count(ia.idaluno) FROM inscricaoaluno ia INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.idaluno = ia.idaluno
WHERE a.idpessoa_juridica = e.idpessoa_juridica AND ia.idprova = p.idprova) qtd, e.nome, e.idpessoa_juridica , p.descprova, p.idprova  
FROM escolas e
CROSS JOIN prova p
GROUP BY e.nome, e.idpessoa_juridica , p.descprova, p.idprova  
ORDER BY e.nome;
```

Uma sintaxe alternativa pode ser:

```
SELECT (SELECT count(ia.idaluno) FROM inscricaoaluno ia INNER JOIN alunos a ON a.idaluno = ia.idaluno
WHERE a.idpessoa_juridica = e.idpessoa_juridica AND ia.idprova = p.idprova) qtd, e.nome, e.idpessoa_juridica , p.descprova, p.idprova  
FROM escolas e, prova p
GROUP BY e.nome, e.idpessoa_juridica , p.descprova, p.idprova  
ORDER BY e.nome;
```

Comment: @Marcelo, só agora que vi que é para Oracle. Pode confirmar a sintaxe da última query (virgula ao invés de `CROSS JOIN`)?

Comment: Sim, os dois `selects` executam da mesma forma, não conhecia esse relacionamento do tipo `cross`, mas pelo que vejo é a mesma coisa que eu colocar os dois depois do `from` correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Eu prefiro a primeira forma pois fica mais claro o que está acontecendo na query. Uma virgula é fácil passar despercebida, mas um `CROSS JOIN` não =)

Comment: Em relação a desempenho, em testes que fiz aqui no meu ambiente, as três formas possuem praticamente a mesma performance